# Why won't my Jbutton do anything on click?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, onclick, jframe

I've been trying to make it so my button will close out of the frame on click but it never does anything. I've looked through several stackoverflow threads but none of them seems to work on my this.. here is what I have so far

```
    JButton start = new JButton("Start");
    start.setBounds(251, 216, 119, 23);

    start.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

            try {
                int hpToEat = Integer.parseInt(GUI.textField.getText());
                Frost.hp = hpToEat;
            } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
                GUI.textField.setText("");
            }
            setVisible(false);
        }
    });
    contentPane.add(start);
```

I have tried making a closeFrame method which uses super.dispose(); and I've also tried system.exit(0);

Does anyone have any idea as to why My button won't do What i want it to do?

Someone requested the rest of my code so here it is:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;


public class GUI extends JFrame{

private JPanel contentPane;
public static JTextField textField;


/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                GUI frame = new GUI();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public GUI() {

    //LABELS ===================================================================================================
```

Comment: Do you even have errors?

Comment: Quick note: `start.addActionListener(e -> {System.out.println("You clicked the button");});` If that doesn't print out "You clicked..:" then there is something else wrong. Like contentPane not being added to the window or something else. Try it simple like this at first.

Comment: Is `GUI` a reference to your GUI or the name of your GUI class?
If it's the name of your class, you should write `GUI.this.setVisible(false)`

Comment: add some more code showing how you made your GUI

Comment: @HummelingEngineering GUI was referring to my class yes. But your suggestion didn't work :(

Comment: @user125535 If `GUI` is a reference to your GUI you should write `GUI.setVisible(false)`.
Though I agree with the other commenters that showing more code will clarify the issue. Just strip it to the essence and add debug statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `GUI.textfield` is not what you think it is. You're shadowing the field here:

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField();
```

That creates a *local* variable by the name `textField`, it does not set the static field you're using in the action listener. A quick fix would be writing just:

```
textField = new JTextField();
```

However, I recommend getting out of the habit of using static fields. That approach does not scale. Furthermore, *don't use absolute positioning*. It leads to no end of trouble (just browse a few questions in the swing tag for examples). Learn to use layout managers right from the start.

Comment: @user125535 When `textField` is uninitialized, `GUI.textField.getText()` throws a `NullPointerException`, so `setVisible()` is not reached. The exception is caught by swing, so the program keeps running, but you should see the stack trace in the console.